# Install and run scroll magic on a angular ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8, scrollmagic

how is the best way to set up and use scroll magic in an angular ionic app?

I find this package but a don't know how to install.

it's possible to work with components or need to be just onde big scene?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-scroll-magic

https://scrollmagic.io

thank you

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by "work with components or need to be just one big scene", but instructions for installing that package and how to use it in an angular  application can be found here https://github.com/homerjam/angular-scroll-magic#readme

Comment: I see but i don't understand the step 3 
`3 - Add hj.scrollMagic to app's module dependencies`
I even try to google 'app's module dependencies' but i have found nothing looks like
Thanks Mike

Comment: When you add global dependencies to an angular app you do so in your app.module.ts file where appropriate, but with that said looking, after looking a little closer, that package seems to be pretty dated and poorly documented. I do not know that it would be compatible with recent versions of angular. Id suggest taking a look at this alternative instead: https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic

Comment: Thanks again Mike
I find out  that this library is actually for  AngularJS (version 1 of Angular)
I have been looking at original package but don't find a way to set up, most of the other posts involving scroll magic use webpack and none of this use iconic (who tent to work with the scroll in his way - <ion content>, <ion-app>, etc )

Answer (score 0):

I find out why i haven't been able to set up the library, it is because is for AngularJS (version 1 of Angular), thank all for the assist

Related post: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/install-and-run-scroll-magic-on-a-angular-ionic-app/177749